# Error coming during installation veil-evasion

Tags: package-management, software-installation

[image]

I have already downloaded `veil-evasion` but i can't install it

```
$ apt-get install veil-evasion
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission Denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg), are you root?
$ sudo -i
# cd Veil-Evasion
-bash: cd: Veil-Evasion/: no such file or directory
# apt-get install Veil-Evasion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package Veil-Evasion
```

Comment: First of all, packet names are case-sensitive, so veil-invasion and Veil-Invasion are not the same. Next, if you have downloaded the application, it probably shouldn't be installed with 'apg -get install'. Wasn't there install instructions on the site from where you downloaded ?

Comment: Just type `apt-get install veil-evasion`.  Like Soren said, watch how you type, between capital and small letters.

Answer (score 0):

The package you are trying to install has not any repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Use [This Link](https://github.com/Veil-Framework/Veil-Evasion) For downloading and installing `veil-evasion`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip   
pip install --user pycrypto    
sudo apt-get -y install git
git clone https://github.com/Veil-Framework/Veil-Evasion.git
cd Veil-Evasion/
cd setup
sudo sh setup.sh -c
```